# Symfony2 Ajax Infinite Scroll

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, symfony, infinite-scroll

I am completely new to Symfony2 and don't understand fully routing and templating. Please help with following issue:
I need to implement infinite scroll with Symfony 2 and Ajax. I have indexController that gets 10 gallery items from db. I want to get 10 more items every time I scroll down.
Here is controller:

```
 /**
 * @Route("/", name="gallery_homepage")
 */
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getEntityManager();

    if($request->isXmlHttpRequest())
    {
        $page = $request->get('page', 1);
        $limit = 10;
        $start = $page * $limit - $limit;

        $objects = $em->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('o')
            ->from('ObjectBundle:Object',  'o')
            ->getQuery()
            ->setFirstResult($start)
            ->setMaxResults($limit)
            ->getResult();

        $response = json_decode($objects);

        return new Response(???));
    }
    else
    {

    }
}
```

This is twig template

```
{% block body %}
<section class="container">
<ul class="printedall">
    {% for object in objects %}
        <li class="printedimgs">
            <a class="object_prints" href="object.url">
                <img src="object.imageURL"/>
            </a>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
</section>
{% endblock %}
```

What response must controller return to get 10 items from db and append them to displayed items?

This is javascript

```
 is_processing = false;
 last_page = false;
 function addMoreElements() {
     is_processing = true;
     $.ajax({
         type: "GET",
         //FOS Routing
         url: Routing.generate('gallery_homepage', {page: page}),
         success: function(data) {
             if (data.html.length > 0) {
                 $('.printedall').append(data.html);
                 page = page + 1;

            last_page = data.last_page;
        } else {
            last_page = true;
        }
        is_processing = false;
    },
    error: function(data) {
        is_processing = false;
    }
});
 }

 $(window).scroll(function() {
     var wintop = $(window).scrollTop(), docheight = $(document).height(),      winheight = $(window).height();

     var scrolltrigger = 0.80;
     if ((wintop / (docheight - winheight)) > scrolltrigger) {

    if (last_page === false && is_processing === false) {
        addMoreElements();
         }
     }
 });
```

Comment: You need to use a javascript plugin to do the pagination like an infinite scroll -> https://github.com/infinite-scroll/infinite-scroll

Comment: You can achieve it without any additional plugin.
Here is example can help you in AJAX related issues http://www.sgeek.org/how-to-implement-infinite-scroll-using-jquery-ajax-php/

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `Request` class from your controller from which you'll know whether the request is AJAX or not. You also have to call the `setFirstResult` and `setMaxResults` method on your query object:

```php
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

// ...

public function indexAction(Request $request) {
    if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        //~ Is AJAX Request

        $offset = $request->get('offset');
        $limit = $request->get('limit');

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getEntityManager();

        $objects = $em->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('o')
            ->from('ThreedBundle:Threedobject',  'o')
            ->where('o.status = 2 AND o.showGallery = 1')
            ->getQuery()
            ->setFirstResult($offset)
            ->setMaxResults($limit)
            ->getResult();
    } else {
        //~ Request is not AJAX
    }
}
```

For the infinite scroll you can use any jquery infinite scroll plugin:

e.g. http://infiniteajaxscroll.com/examples/basic/page1.html